# jQuery - 1 out of 3 div's but random

Tags: jquery, html, random

Heyy

I want to program a "Rock Paper Scissors" with a computer. Now, when I choose one of the 3 options, I want the computer to put in a random object - but how?
I came up with something like this

jQuery
( when i click #rock, put in a random div from below)

```
$('#rock').on('click',function() {
           $('#putHere').text($("#rock" || "#paper" || "#scissors").text());
          });
```

HTML

```
 <div id="rock">rock</div>
 <div id="paper">paper</div>
 <div id="scissors">scissors</div>
```

May be misunderstandable but yeah.. I tried my best.. Thaks for the help though

Comment: @Manishh i was searching for so long but i saw it right after i asked the question.. so yeah it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold the selectors and generate index randomly using [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) method.

```js
var sel = ["#rock", "#paper", "#scissors"];

$('#rock').on('click', function() {
  $('#putHere').text($(sel[Math.floor(Math.random() * sel.length)]).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rock">rock</div>
<div id="paper">paper</div>
<div id="scissors">scissors</div>


<div id="putHere"></div>
```

---

Or use collection of elements instead of array of selectors.

```js
var $el = $("#rock,#paper,#scissors");

$('#rock').on('click', function() {
  $('#putHere').text($el.eq([Math.floor(Math.random() * $el.length)]).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rock">rock</div>
<div id="paper">paper</div>
<div id="scissors">scissors</div>


<div id="putHere"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been stuck for way to long -_- :D Can vote in 8min

Answer (score 1):

You can try this thing

```
var myArray = ['#rock', '#paper', '#scissors']; 
$('#putHere').text(myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]);
```